# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a notification payload coming from the server side (Firebase cloud messaging) and it consists of the usual *userInfo* with an array of integers and I can't find a way to cast the array under the **"records_id"** key to **[Int]**

here is the structure of the *userInfo* which I am dealing with:

```
[
    AnyHashable("title"): title, 
    AnyHashable("sound"): true, 
    AnyHashable("aps"): {
        alert =     {
            body = "notif body";
            title = "notif title";
        };
        "content-available" = 1;
        "mutable-content" = 1;
        sound = true;
    }, 
    AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, 
    AnyHashable("action"): stacked, 
    AnyHashable("record_id"): [61,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97], 
    AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1563172453549130, 
    AnyHashable("gcm.notification.fromAPI"): true, 
    AnyHashable("gcm.notification.action"): stacked, 
    AnyHashable("body"): notif body, 
    AnyHashable("gcm.notification.record_id"): [61,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97], 
    AnyHashable("fromAPI"): true
]
```

here is my code in **AppDelegate**:

```
    // receive notification while app in foreground
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        registerNotification(userInfo)

    }

    // register notifications records
    func registerNotification(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        print(userInfo) // this print the above userinfo structure that I show earlier 

        let ids = userInfo["record_id"] as! [Int]

        for id in ids {
            print("new record: \(id)")
        }
    }
```

The above code throw the following error while trying to cast to **[Int]**:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1bebadf60) to 'NSArray' (0x1bebae960).
```

Comment: Show. Your. Code.

Comment: it is api response or notification?

Comment: We can't help you unless you show your code. Show the payload coming in. Show where the `userInfo` parameter comes from.

Comment: I edited the question now you can see the actual payload and how am I dealing with it. please help me figure out how to cast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
let ids = userInfo["records_id"] as! String
let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from:Data(ids.utf8))
print(res)
```

Comment: (Realized that the question doesn't actually involve JSON; it really is a dictionary from Cocoa… deleted my Decodable discussion.)

Comment: already tried this i got this error:
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1bebadf60) to 'NSArray' (0x1bebae960).

Comment: see edit.......................

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for days. Thank you, this works perfectly. Could you explain why you have to decode the JSON before setting the array? When printed in the console, it appears that userinfo data is already formatted properly but it fails.